# Can you condition an excel macro based on cell content?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

For work, I download a a series of spreadsheets that have quiz names in one of the cell columns.  There are generally 5-10 attempts per quiz and about 10 quizzes that are reported in the spreadsheet.

I have a macro that sorts the data by quiz name so the attempts are grouped together, but I want to add a space before and after each grouping, so that the different quizzes are separated.  Can you do this with a macro?

For example if I had:

```
Quiz Name 1
Quiz Name 1
Quiz Name 1
Quiz Name 2
Quiz Name 2
Quiz Name 2
```

Could I have a macro that recognizes where the quiz name changes and adds a space so that it looks like:

```
Quiz Name 1
Quiz Name 1
Quiz Name 1
-blank row-
Quiz Name 2
Quiz Name 2
Quiz Name 2
```

I can add a row with a macro, but I don't know about conditioning it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To be clear when you mention `macro` do you mean a recorded sequence of actions or do you mean a program written in code?

Comment: A program written in code.

Comment: You state `quiz names in one of the cell columns` but the way you represent your sample data seems to indicate that the names are all in one `Row` and you would like each ***set*** of names in there own row with each attempt in it's own column?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that the format editor changed my formatting. I edited the above to match my issue more specifically.

Comment: Are you using excel 2010/2007/2003?

Comment: Excel 2010, sorry I didn't think the version was pertinent for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit for column two to filter on**

The column number is the second part of the cells(x,y) notation, where row is the first, so this loops throughout all rows in whatever column y is specified as, so changing this to 2 should give the correct results.

```
Sub insertrows()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
If Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
Rows(i).Insert
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

How about this?

```
Sub insertrows()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
Rows(i).Insert
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel did not like this line of code: `lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Was about to post something almost identical, +1

Comment: @ThomasNolan - what is your sheet called? If the sheet name is the issue, try Activesheet.Cells instead

Comment: Okay, that looks like it is working, but one last question: I need it to sort by column 2 not column 1, is there anything I can do to specify column 2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can condition an excel macro based on cell contents AND you can have a macro that recognizes where the quiz name changes and adds a space.

***NOTE:*** This was not intended to be a *smart* answer but simply given the question and the way it was worded I was under the impression maybe the OP just wanted to know if it was possible or not before attempting to trying to do it on his own.

As I many times like to see if something is possible but then try to figure out how it is possible myself, then after i figure it out I **Then** try to research how others have/would do it and compare it to my own code. I feel when I do things this way I have a much better understanding of how things work and why. Rather then just having the knowledge of this makes this happen.

Here is some code to help:

```
Sub InsertRowAtChange()

Dim CurrentValue As String
Dim Lastinstance As Long
Dim CurrentCell As Range


CurrentValue = Range("A1").Value
Set CurrentCell = Range("A1")

Do While CurrentValue <> ""

    Lastinstance = Range("A:A").Find(What:=CurrentValue, After:=CurrentCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

      Set CurrentCell = Range("A" & Lastinstance + 1)
      CurrentValue = CurrentCell

      Rows(Lastinstance + 1).Insert

Loop


End Sub
```

And another option Just incase you don't like loops at would prefer to use all built in Excel functions and formulas to get the job done.

```
Sub InsertRowAtChange2()

Dim DataRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long


LastRow = Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row

Set DataRange = Range("B2", Range("B" & LastRow))

With DataRange

     .EntireColumn.Insert 'Add a temp column for a formula

     .Offset(0, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(NOT(ISNA(R[-1]C)),R[-1]C[1]<>RC[1]),1,"""")"

     .Offset(0, -1) = .Offset(0, -1).Value 'Remove Formulas

     Set DataRange = .Offset(0, -1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) 'Numbers represent changes in rows

 End With

 'Add a row at each change in data

 If WorksheetFunction.Count(DataRange) > 0 Then

    DataRange.EntireRow.Insert

 End If

     'Delete Temp Column

     DataRange.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete



On Error GoTo 0

Set DataRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Would you be able to help with the VB script by chance?

Comment: Being a technology instructor and having taught myself website devlopment and various coding languages I completely understand that.  However, I have no foundation is VB script and was just looking for some help from experts because I tried researching this to no avail. From research I could add the row with the macro, but was unable to specifically find a condition for what I was looking for.

Comment: @ThomasNolan I have updated my answer with code. It will Look at the first value and then search backwards for the last instance of that value then insert a row after it. If you need a different Column just change the `A` in the range calls to the column you want and if your data has headers you should also change the `Range("A1")`'s to `Range("A2")`. Using this code will help speed things up as it won't have to loop through every cell but instead will skip right to where it needs to insert a row.

Comment: @ThomasNolan I have again updated my answer with another option. My second Macro should work for your request of using the Second column for the values.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Group_2()
Dim LASTROW As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim ROW_Beg As Long
Dim ROW_End As Long
I = 1
For I = 1 To 10000
    If Cells(I, 1).Value = -1 Then
        LASTROW = I - 1
    End If
Next

ROW_Beg = 0
ROW_End = 0

For I = 1 To LASTROW
    If (Cells(I, 1).Value = 2 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 3 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 4 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 5 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 6 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 7 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 8 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 9 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 10) Then
        If (ROW_Beg <> 0) Then
            ROW_End = I
        End If
    Else
        ROW_Beg = I + 1
    End If
    If ((ROW_Beg <> 0) And (ROW_End <> 0)) Then
        Rows(ROW_Beg & ":" & ROW_End).Group
        ROW_Beg = ROW_Beg + 1
        ROW_End = 0
    End If
Next I


ROW_Beg = 0
ROW_End = 0
    For I = 1 To LASTROW
    If (Cells(I, 1).Value = 3 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 4 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 5 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 6 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 7 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 8 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 9 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 10) Then
        If (ROW_Beg <> 0) Then
            ROW_End = I
        End If
    Else
        ROW_Beg = I + 1
    End If
    If ((ROW_Beg <> 0) And (ROW_End <> 0)) Then
        Rows(ROW_Beg & ":" & ROW_End).Group
        ROW_Beg = ROW_Beg + 1
        ROW_End = 0
    End If
Next I

ROW_Beg = 0
ROW_End = 0
    For I = 1 To LASTROW
    If (Cells(I, 1).Value = 4 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 5 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 6 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 7 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 8 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 9 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 10) Then
        If (ROW_Beg <> 0) Then
            ROW_End = I
        End If
    Else
        ROW_Beg = I + 1
    End If
    If ((ROW_Beg <> 0) And (ROW_End <> 0)) Then
        Rows(ROW_Beg & ":" & ROW_End).Group
        ROW_Beg = ROW_Beg + 1
        ROW_End = 0
    End If
Next I

ROW_Beg = 0
ROW_End = 0
    For I = 1 To LASTROW
    If (Cells(I, 1).Value = 5 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 6 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 7 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 8 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 9 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 10) Then
        If (ROW_Beg <> 0) Then
            ROW_End = I
        End If
    Else
        ROW_Beg = I + 1
    End If
    If ((ROW_Beg <> 0) And (ROW_End <> 0)) Then
        Rows(ROW_Beg & ":" & ROW_End).Group
        ROW_Beg = ROW_Beg + 1
        ROW_End = 0
    End If
Next I

    ROW_Beg = 0
ROW_End = 0
    For I = 1 To LASTROW
    If (Cells(I, 1).Value = 6 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 7 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 8 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 9 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 10) Then
        If (ROW_Beg <> 0) Then
            ROW_End = I
        End If
    Else
        ROW_Beg = I + 1
    End If
    If ((ROW_Beg <> 0) And (ROW_End <> 0)) Then
        Rows(ROW_Beg & ":" & ROW_End).Group
        ROW_Beg = ROW_Beg + 1
        ROW_End = 0
    End If
Next I

    ROW_Beg = 0
ROW_End = 0
    For I = 1 To LASTROW
    If (Cells(I, 1).Value = 7 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 8 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 9 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 10) Then
        If (ROW_Beg <> 0) Then
            ROW_End = I
        End If
    Else
        ROW_Beg = I + 1
    End If
    If ((ROW_Beg <> 0) And (ROW_End <> 0)) Then
        Rows(ROW_Beg & ":" & ROW_End).Group
        ROW_Beg = ROW_Beg + 1
        ROW_End = 0
    End If
Next I

    ROW_Beg = 0
ROW_End = 0
    For I = 1 To LASTROW
    If (Cells(I, 1).Value = 8 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 9 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 10) Then
        If (ROW_Beg <> 0) Then
            ROW_End = I
        End If
    Else
        ROW_Beg = I + 1
    End If
    If ((ROW_Beg <> 0) And (ROW_End <> 0)) Then
        Rows(ROW_Beg & ":" & ROW_End).Group
        ROW_Beg = ROW_Beg + 1
        ROW_End = 0
    End If
Next I

    ROW_Beg = 0
ROW_End = 0
    For I = 1 To LASTROW
    If (Cells(I, 1).Value = 9 Or Cells(I, 1).Value = 10) Then
        If (ROW_Beg <> 0) Then
            ROW_End = I
        End If
    Else
        ROW_Beg = I + 1
    End If
    If ((ROW_Beg <> 0) And (ROW_End <> 0)) Then
        Rows(ROW_Beg & ":" & ROW_End).Group
        ROW_Beg = ROW_Beg + 1
        ROW_End = 0
    End If
Next I


    ROW_Beg = 0
ROW_End = 0
    For I = 1 To LASTROW
    If (Cells(I, 1).Value = 10) Then
        If (ROW_Beg <> 0) Then
            ROW_End = I
        End If
    Else
        ROW_Beg = I + 1
    End If
    If ((ROW_Beg <> 0) And (ROW_End <> 0)) Then
        Rows(ROW_Beg & ":" & ROW_End).Group
        ROW_Beg = ROW_Beg + 1
        ROW_End = 0
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are going to attempt to answer old questions, please at least include an explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing and why this fixes the problem